# Showing a tooltip for a MenuItem

Tags: .net, winforms

I've got a menu that contains, among other things, some most-recently-used file paths.  The paths to these files can be long, so the text sometimes gets clipped like "C:\Progra...\foo.txt"

I'd like to pop a tooltip with the full path when the user hovers over the item, but this doesn't seem possible with the [Tooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) class in .NET 2.0.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are creating your menu items using the [System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.aspx) class you won't have a "ToolTipText" property.

You should use the [System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.aspx) class which is new as of .Net Framework 2.0 and DOES include the "ToolTipText" property.

You also have to remember to specify ShowItemToolTips = True on the MenuStrip control

Comment: This was an old application upgraded from .NET 1.1 and was using a MainMenu with MenuItems. I had never seen the MenuStrip class until now. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how this works... I have a custom Form with a toolTip class, and all controls I add to that Form with the Design screen work fine.  The custom class I wrote (that inherits a StatusStrip) and its child controls don't work.  I can assign a value to the ToolTipText of my ToolStripLabel objects, but the tooltip never appears.   I tried binding the ToolStripLabel to the ToolTip, as another poster suggested, but tooltip.SetToolTip() does not accept ToolStrip controls; it only accepts Control items, which ToolStrip items are *not*.

Comment: @Tinkerer_CardTracker The question asked was about showing a tooltip for a menu item. It sounds like your issue is completely different. You might get a better response by creating a new question.

Comment: You also have to remember to specify ShowItemToolTips = True on the MenuStrip control.

Comment: @RenniePet That was the thing I was missing. Should edit this answer.

Answer (score 3):

On the MenusTrip set "ShowItemToolTips = True" and on the ToolStripMenuItem set your ToolTipText

```
yourMenuStrip.ShowItemToolTips = true;
yourToolStripMenuItem.ToolTipText = "some txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

May be that I misunderstood you problem, but why do you need to use the `Tooltip` class? You can assign your text to the [ToolTipText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa978609%28VS.71%29.aspx) property and it will be shown to the user.

Comment: I think it's the ToolTip property.

Comment: Control class doesn't have ToolTip property. It has ToolTipText

Comment: Oops sorry I'm looking at a different MenuItem class.

Comment: If you want to play with the various time-values of the Tooltip class you may want more than is provided with the ToolTipText property.

Answer (score 1):

Tooltip is set manually by:

```
testToolStripMenuItem2.ToolTipText = "My tooltip text";
```

The MenuItem can for example be part of this menu constellation: a menu strip with a menu item and a sub menu item. (This plumbing code is generated automatically for you in the code behind designer file if you use visual studio)

```
MenuStrip menuStrip1;    
ToolStripMenuItem testToolStripMenuItem; // Menu item on menu bar
menuStrip1.Items.Add(testToolStripMenuItem);

ToolStripMenuItem testToolStripMenuItem2; // Sub menu item
testToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(testToolStripMenuItem2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on CodeProject that implements a derived version of ToolStrip with custom tool tip support. This could be useful in situations where the default tool tip support is not flexible enough. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/376643/ToolStrip-with-custom-ToolTip

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you forgot to associate the tooltip with the control using [SetToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip.aspx).