# Change tool tip timeout on menustrip in winforms?

Tags: winforms, timeout, tooltip, menustrip

How to extend tool tip timeout when hovering on menu items in a menustrip (in winforms)?

I set it like this:

```
toolStripMenuItem1.ToolTipText = "foo";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you use the [`Tooltip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) class, by setting the `AutoPopDelay` property to a higher value (MSDN: [Change the Delay of the Windows Forms ToolTip Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba01s7kc.aspx)).

However, if you try to use the `Tooltip` class to set a tooltip on a `ToolStripMenuItem` like this:

```
ToolTip1.SetToolTip(toolStripMenuItem1, "check it yo!")
```

You'll get the following error:

```
'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem' cannot be 
 converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.
```

Check out this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58245/945456) for ways around that.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on CodeProject that implements a derived version of ToolStrip with custom tool tip support. That could probably be used to do what you want to do. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/376643/ToolStrip-with-custom-ToolTip