# Add tooltip to FlyoutMenu

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `FlyoutMenu` in my uwp app. It works fine, but I want to add tooltips to some items. Can I do that?

If you are not working on uwp, the related question here may be of interest:
[Showing a tooltip for a MenuItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245/showing-a-tooltip-for-a-menuitem)

```
class WindowsMenuFlyoutItem: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MenuFlyoutItem
{
    public ICommonMenuItem InnerItem { get; set; }
    public WindowsMenuFlyoutItem (MyModelObject inner) {
        this.Text = inner.GetTitle().Text;
        this.Tapped += WindowsMenuFlyoutItem_Tapped;
        // set tooltip?
    }

    private void WindowsMenuFlyoutItem_Tapped(Object sender,
                                             Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // handler here . . .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void WindowsMenuFlyoutItem_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuFlyoutItem item = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
    ToolTipService.SetToolTip(item, "tooltip...");
}
```

Or if you want to set it immediately before the item is tapped:

```
public class WindowsMenuFlyoutItem : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MenuFlyoutItem
{
    public ICommonMenuItem InnerItem { get; set; }
    public WindowsMenuFlyoutItem(MyModelObject inner)
    {
        this.Text = inner.GetTitle().Text;
        this.Tapped += WindowsMenuFlyoutItem_Tapped;

        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToolTipService.SetToolTip(this, "tooltip...");
    }
}
```